# Kinect for Windows v2 vs Kinect for Xbox One

Tags: kinect

I have found the [official page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/meetkinect/features.aspx) that describes the hardware specifications for **Kinect for Windows v2**. But I cannot seem to find the hardware specification for **Kinect for Xbox One**. I just want to know if there is any difference in hardware specification between these two devices.

Comment: Unlike situation with the first generation of Kinect hardware there are no differences between the Xbox One version and the PC version except for the included cables that come with the PC version.

Comment: Do you maybe have a source of this information? I was searching for specification comparison between these two versions and I just can not find it.

Comment: There isn't information on the differences because there are none.  As I said the original revision ( Kinect v1 ) for the PC had some performance improvements, these were documented, there are zero performance improvements for the ( Kinect v2 ) for PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as @Ramhound said on the Question comment, these two sensor are functionally identical. Recently MS also announced in a blog that they will no longer produce Kinect for Windows v2 sensor, developers should just use **Kinect for Xbox One sensor** + **Kinect Adapter for Windows**. And they also said in that official blog:

> both Kinect for Xbox One and Kinect for Windows v2 sensors are
>   functionally identical, our Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0 works exactly
>   the same with either.

Here is the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2015/04/02/microsoft-to-consolidate-the-kinect-for-windows-experience-around-a-single-sensor.aspx) for that blog.

Comment: Are the resolution (color and depth) of them also the same?

Answer (score -1):

The firmware on the devices are different. I tried to connect a Kinect for window to my xbox one s and it doesn't recognise it. However both would work on a PC for windows development.